# When using side by side view in MS Word, is there a way make the pages larger? There's a lot of wasted space

Tags: microsoft-word

Take a look at this screenshot. This is what a side by side document looks like on my monitor. There's a lot of gray space above and below. Is there a way to zoom on on the pages to take advantage of all the real estate I have on my monitor?

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a Zoom in the View menu?

Comment: Or does Ctrl-mouse wheel allow zooming?

Comment: @Tetsujin, zoom is disabled

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, ctrl+mouse wheel just makes more pages visible when I zoom out. Nothing happens when I zoom in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there's no way to go above 100% while in Side-by-Side mode which is the way I want to view the document. The one workaround I did find was to go to Windows Setting > Display > Scale and Layout and increase the scaling from 100% to 150%. It's not ideal, but works well enough when I am reading really long documents.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 10/10/23:

I just noticed that you are in focus mode or read mode. In that mode, you can't go below 100%. But if you switch back to the "Print Layout", then you'll be able to have the pages side-by-side and also go below 100% zoom.

EDIT END 10/10/23

2 Options:

- Use the zoom scale in the bottom right of your Word window
- Go to the "View" tab, select "Zoom" and then set the desired zoom value

In case you'd like to **always have a specific zoom view upon start of Word**, you can easily use a macro (see 1 minute video instruction https://youtu.be/Dtnn-IV3OnY):

```
Public Sub AutoOpen()
If Word.Documents.Count Then
    ThisDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.PageColumns = 2
    ThisDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 150
End If
End Sub
```

The `150` at the end of the 4th line of the code is the zoom value.

Comment: Zoom scale does nothing in the side by side view. When I make the windows smaller, it goes does down below 100%, but never goes up over 100%

Comment: @PBG I update my answer